# extract the matrix from strel matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the strel function from matlab, and get its matrix value alone. When I define a strel object, as follows,

```
    SE = strel('disk',2);
```

I get the following

```
     SE

     SE =

       Flat STREL object containing 13 neighbors.

     Neighborhood:
       0     0     1     0     0
       0     1     1     1     0
       1     1     1     1     1
       0     1     1     1     0
       0     0     1     0     0
```

But when I try to use it as a matrix, am getting error. Is there a way where I can just extract the matrix part of this object? Please help me.

Comment: Wow you asked this, nice. Btw where are you now a days?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the STREL object's getnhood() function:

```
SE.getnhood()

ans = 
       0     0     1     0     0
       0     1     1     1     0
       1     1     1     1     1
       0     1     1     1     0
       0     0     1     0     0
```